# mean across multiple date columns

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a large data frame with some columns that are dates, but in character format, like so:

```
name <- c("John ", "Jay", "Carla")
X3.12.2010 <- c(20, 10, 9)
X3.19.2010 <- c(19, 8, 44)
X3.26.2010 <- c(10, 100, 999)
X4.3.2010 <- c(8, 1, 23)
X4.10.2010 <- c(8, 10, 238)
X4.17.2010 <- c(28, 17, 27)
X4.24.2010 <- c(11, 12, 45)
g <- data.frame(name, X3.12.2010, X3.19.2010, X3.26.2010, X4.3.2010, X4.10.2010, X4.17.2010, X4.24.2010)
```

However, I want the date columns to be in 'yyyymm' format, then take the mean for each unique combination of date and name.  I used the following code to convert the date columns:

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

colnames(g)[2:8] <- ifelse(nchar(sub(" X", "", paste(substrRight(colnames(g)[2:8], 4),str_extract(colnames(g)[2:8], "[^.]+")))) < 6, 
                                   sub(" X", 0, paste(substrRight(colnames(g)[2:8], 4),str_extract(colnames(g)[2:8], "[^.]+"))), 
                                   sub(" X", "", paste(substrRight(colnames(g)[2:8], 4),str_extract(colnames(g)[2:8], "[^.]+"))))
 print(g)

   name 201003 201003 201003 201004 201004 201004 201004
1 John      20     19     10      8      8     28     11
2   Jay     10      8    100      1     10     17     12
3 Carla      9     44    999     23    238     27     45
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
   name X201003 X201004
1 John    16.33   13.75
2   Jay   39.33   10.00
3 Carla  350.66   83.25
```

Is there a way to produce this?  Thanks.

Comment: it's a bit unclear whether your data is in a dataframe or not based on your sample code

Comment: you didn't build any data frame, and your variables contain a different number of values so cannot be put in a data frame, it's also unclear how you get your expected output

Comment: You have multiple columns with same names? Looks like you need to do some reshaping and then get the `mean` for each combination of `name` and date.

Comment: @MikePalmice thanks, I just changed the sample code.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I just updated so that its three values per date.  I get an error when I use `as.data.frame`.  The column names (dates) as listed have been changed from 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.

Comment: @AntoniosK what do you mean by reshaping?

Answer (score 1):

**Comment on storing data**

It's a good practice not to have columns with the same name. It doesn't make any sense and it would be great to correct it on the source (i.e. from where you get that data). As an example of the best way to store this kind of data in order to do further calculations/modeling/plotting etc. is this

```
d = data.frame(name = c("John", "Jay", "Carla","John", "Jay", "Carla","John", "Jay", "Carla"),
               month = c(201003, 201003, 201003,201003, 201003, 201003,201004, 201004, 201004),
               order = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1),
               value = c(20,10,9,19,8,44,8,10,238))

#    name  month order value
# 1  John 201003     1    20
# 2   Jay 201003     1    10
# 3 Carla 201003     1     9
# 4  John 201003     2    19
# 5   Jay 201003     2     8
# 6 Carla 201003     2    44
# 7  John 201004     1     8
# 8   Jay 201004     1    10
# 9 Carla 201004     1   238
```

**Solution to posted question**

In order to reshape we have to create different names for your columns and then extract the time at a later stage in order to group data and calculate the mean:

```
library(tidyverse)

# set as data frame to get columns with different names
g = data.frame(g)

g %>%
  gather(time,value,-name) %>%                        # reshape data
  mutate(time = gsub('X([^.]+)|.', '\\1', time)) %>%  # get time from column names (everything between "X" and ".")
  group_by(name, time) %>%                            # for each name and time
  summarise(MEAN = mean(value)) %>%                   # get mean value
  ungroup() %>%                                       # forget the grouping
  spread(time, MEAN)                                  # reshape again

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   name    `201003` `201004`
#   <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Carla      351.      83.2
# 2 Jay         39.3     10  
# 3 John       16.3     13.8
```

Comment: @Is this `dplyr`?  What is `time`?  I get that they shouldn't have the same name, but I needed a way to organize them by month.

Comment: Time is a new column that is created when we reshape data. You can run the above code step by step to see how it works.

Comment: When I copy the code above, I only get `3` and `4` in the column names.  Also, what if I have more than one column like `name`?

Comment: You have to apply your `substrRight` and get numeric column names. My solution is tailored to the example you provided. It's not going to work if your columns are like `X3.12.2010`. If you have multiple columns like `name` you just group by those as well.

Comment: When applied to my full dataset, I include all of my columns like name in both `gather` and `group_by` statements. I get an Error: Columns must have unique names. Does it matter that all the variables are listed as factor in `str`?  There is also an error that reads `Item attributes not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped`

Comment: Last one seems like a warning, so it doesn't break anything. For error I need data to investigate. Best thing to do is get a subset of your data that produces this error and post it as a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850172/r-tidyverse-calculate-mean-across-multiple-columns-with-same-name