# r tidyverse - calculate mean across multiple columns with same name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that is collected weekly, a snippet of which is like so, via `dput`:

```
p <- structure(list(railroad = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
c("All Other Railroads", 
"BNSF Railway Company", "CN", "CSX Transportation", "Norfolk Southern", 
"The Kansas City Southern Railway and Kansas City Southern de Mexico, S.A. de 
C.V. Consolidated ", 
"Union Pacific Railroad"), class = "factor"), measure = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Cars On Line - By Car Owner", 
"Cars On Line - By Car Type", "Terminal Dwell (Hours)", "Train Speed (MPH)"
), class = "factor"), category = structure(c(76L, 35L, 4L, 76L, 
35L, 29L), .Label = c("All Trains", "Allentown, PA", "Baltimore, MD", 
"Barstow, CA", "Bellevue, OH", "Birmingham, AL", "Box", "Buffalo, NY", 
"Chattanooga, TN", "Chicago (Proviso), IL", "Chicago, IL", "Cincinnati, OH", 
"Coal Unit", "Columbus, OH", "Conway, PA", "Corbin, KY", "Covered Hopper", 
"Decatur, IL", "Denver, CO", "Elkhart, IN", "Entire Railroad", 
"Fond du Lac Yard, WI", "Foreign RR", "Fort Worth, TX", "Galesburg, IL", 
"Gondola", "Grain Unit", "Hamlet, NC", "Harrison Yard (Memphis), TN", 
"Hinkle, OR", "Houston (Englewood), TX", "Houston (Settegast), TX", 
"Houston, TX", "Indianapolis, IN", "Intermodal", "Jackson Yard, MS", 
"Jackson, MS", "Kansas City, KS", "Kansas City, MO", "Knoxville, TN", 
"Laredo, TX", "Lincoln, NE", "Linwood, NC", "Livonia, LA", "Louisville, KY", 
"MacMillan Yard (Toronto), ON", "Macon, GA", "Manifest", "Markham Yard, IL", 
"Memphis, TN", "Monterrey, NL", "Montgomery, AL", "Multilevel", 
"Nashville, TN", "New Orleans, LA", "North Little Rock, AR", 
"North Platte East, NE", "North Platte West, NE", "Northtown, MN", 
"Nuevo Laredo, TM", "Open Hopper", "Other", "Pasco, WA", "Pct. Private", 
"Pine Bluff, AR", "Private", "Roanoke, VA", "Roseville, CA", 
"Russell, KY", "San Luis Potosi, SL", "Sanchez, TM", "Selkirk, NY", 
"Sheffield, AL", "Shreveport, LA", "Symington Yard (Winnipeg), MB", 
"System", "Tank", "Tascherau Yard (Montreal), QC", "Thornton Yard (Vancouver), 
BC", 
"Toledo, OH", "Total", "Tulsa, OK", "Walker Yard (Edmonton), AB", 
"Waycross, GA", "West Colton, CA", "Willard, OH"), class = "factor"), 
`201510` = c(66923, 33.9, 39.3, 40227, 30.8, 17.5), `201510` = c(66637, 
32.6, 56.6, 40778, 30.9, 18.3), `201510` = c(66309, 33.4, 
44.9, 40407, 30.5, 17.3), `201511` = c(65980, 34.6, 37.5, 
40316, 30.6, 17.5), `201511` = c(67034, 34.6, 43.1, 40174, 
30.4, 18.7)), row.names = c(1L, 15L, 21L, 33L, 47L, 53L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

There are 143 columns total, and columns 4 - 143 are numeric.  I would like to calculate the mean for all columns that have the same column name.  So below there is column `201510` repeated 3 times and column `201511` repeated twice.  The desired output is the mean of each column repeated.  For example, `201510` will have the following values:

```
`201510`
[1] 66623.00000    33.30000    46.93333 40470.66667    30.73333    17.70000
```

I have tried the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

p = data.frame(p)

p %>%
  gather(time,value,railroad, measure, category) %>%                       
  mutate(time = gsub('X([^.]+)|.', '\\1', time)) %>%  
  group_by(time, value, railroad, measure, category) %>%                            
  summarise(MEAN = mean(value)) %>%                   
  ungroup() %>%                                       
  spread(time, MEAN)
```

Which produces the following error:

```
`Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
Column `railroad` is unknown
In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped `
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @camille just edited code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is the non-unique column names. The tidyverse mostly assumes unique column names and many functions add suffixes to make them unique if they were not already, as do many base functions, so in all the solutions below we simply avoid using any such function.  We can still use magrittr, purrr and certain base functions still allow this too.

(1), (2) and (4) only use magrittr.  (1a) uses purrr and in (3) we use tidyr and dplyr but only after converting to long form.

All solutions append a column whose name is of the form `mean.*` for each unique name among the numeric columns.  In the example in the question there are two unique names among the numeric columns so for that example it appends two columns and they are named `mean.201510` and `mean.201511` as shown below.  We only show the output in (1) but the output for the rest is similar.

All solutions use two pipelines.  The first consists of the first `%>%` and the second pipleline appears as an argument to `cbind` and is what creates the new columns.

(1), (1a) and (4) are tied for the shortest.

**1) magrittr** `magrittr` itself does not seem to add suffixes.  `cbind` the original data frame `p` with the following.  First convert `p` to a list of columns, extract the numeric components, split that on the column names, convert each component to a data frame and take the rowMeans of each and finally set the names to mean.* .

```
library(magrittr)

p %>%
  cbind(as.list(.) %>%
    Filter(is.numeric, .) %>%
    split(names(.)) %>%
    lapply(as.data.frame) %>%
    lapply(rowMeans) %>%
    setNames(paste0("mean.", names(.)))
  )
```

giving:

```
               railroad                     measure                    category
1  BNSF Railway Company Cars On Line - By Car Owner                      System
15 BNSF Railway Company           Train Speed (MPH)                  Intermodal
21 BNSF Railway Company      Terminal Dwell (Hours)                 Barstow, CA
33                   CN Cars On Line - By Car Owner                      System
47                   CN           Train Speed (MPH)                  Intermodal
53                   CN      Terminal Dwell (Hours) Harrison Yard (Memphis), TN
    201510  201510  201510  201511  201511 mean.201510 mean.201511
1  66923.0 66637.0 66309.0 65980.0 67034.0 66623.00000     66507.0
15    33.9    32.6    33.4    34.6    34.6    33.30000        34.6
21    39.3    56.6    44.9    37.5    43.1    46.93333        40.3
33 40227.0 40778.0 40407.0 40316.0 40174.0 40470.66667     40245.0
47    30.8    30.9    30.5    30.6    30.4    30.73333        30.5
53    17.5    18.3    17.3    17.5    18.7    17.70000        18.1
```

**1a) purrr** Optionally we could replace some of the base functions with their purrr or magrittr equivalent.  We could also translate to purrr in the other solutions.

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

p %>%
  cbind(as.list(.) %>%
    keep(is.numeric) %>%
    split(names(.)) %>%
    map(as.data.frame) %>%
    map(rowMeans) %>%
    set_names(paste0("mean.", names(.)))
  )
```

**2) apply/tapply** Another possibility is to `tapply` across each row separately.  The `apply` line does this.

```
library(magrittr)

p %>%
  cbind(as.list(.) %>%
    Filter(is.numeric, .) %>%
    do.call("cbind", .) %>%
    apply(1, tapply, colnames(.), mean) %>%
    t %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    setNames(paste0("mean.", names(.)))
  )
```

**3) as.data.frame.table**  This approach uses dplyr and tidyr for most operations but uses `as.data.frame.table` from base instead of `gather` to convert to long form in order to avoid the probem of adding suffixes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

p %>%
  cbind(as.list(.) %>%
    keep(is.numeric) %>%
    do.call("cbind", .) %>%
    as.data.frame.table %>%
    group_by(Var2, Var1) %>%
    summarize(Mean = mean(Freq)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    spread(Var2, Mean) %>%
    select(-Var1) %>%
    set_names(paste0("mean.", names(.)))
  )
```

**4) lm** If `X` is the numeric columns and `mean.` is the column names then `t(coef(lm(t(X) ~ mean. - 1)))` gives the required mean columns so:

```
library(magrittr)

p %>%
  cbind(as.list(.) %>%
    Filter(is.numeric, .) %>%
    do.call("cbind", .) %>%
    { lm(t(.) ~ mean. - 1, data.frame(mean. = colnames(.))) } %>%
    coef %>%
    t
  )
```

Comment: @jvalent, Then you would need to create a grouping variable from them but in the  example shown in the question the column names already form a grouping variable so this is unnecessary provided you don't inadvertently introduce non-uniqueness.  The solutions in this answer all ensure that such non-uniqueness is not inadvertently introduced.

Comment: yeah, I get that I was just curious to see what it would look like.  I totally get that the names SHOULD be unique, for  lots of reasons, but I wanted to create a grouping variable which is why I converted the names the way i did. Anyway, thanks for your help on this.  I ended up going with 1.)

Answer (score 3):

Split the data frame by column names first, and then apply `rowMeans` on each sub data frame;

```
lapply(split.default(p[,4:length(p)], names(p)[4:length(p)]), rowMeans)
#$`201510`
#          1          15          21          33          47          53 
#66623.00000    33.30000    46.93333 40470.66667    30.73333    17.70000 

#$`201511`
#      1      15      21      33      47      53 
#66507.0    34.6    40.3 40245.0    30.5    18.1
```

Even though the above works, you should try to avoid having the same name for different columns, as R will eventually rename those columns to make each column name unique; You'd better rethink how you should work with your data, possibly reshape the data frame so that the year goes into a single column and then you can do group by and aggregate by the year.

```
p %>% 
    # create the row number to identify each row
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    # gather time columns into a single column
    gather('time', 'value', -rn, -railroad, -measure, -category) %>% 
    mutate(time = sub('X([^.]+).*', '\\1', time)) %>% 
    # group and aggregate
    group_by(rn, railroad, measure, category, time) %>% 
    summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% 
    # split value by time
    {split(.$value, .$time)}

#$`201510`
#[1] 66623.00000    33.30000    46.93333 40470.66667    30.73333    17.70000

#$`201511`
#[1] 66507.0    34.6    40.3 40245.0    30.5    18.1
```

Comment: I understand that approach, but I seem to be struggling with that as well.  If you had suggestions on how to do that, I'd appreciate it.  I just added code I used and the error message I got

Comment: Updated the answer with the reshape approach -

Answer (score 0):

Your columns don't have unique names, so you probably didn't understand how tidy data works, Columns Names are not the place to store relevant information, read https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Why tidy data matters is because you are using Its creators functions.

Comment: Even if the columns had unique names the problem would still exist.  I've tried it that way too.

Comment: I honestly can't get a cohesive data frame when copy pasting your example, could you try to simplify it? Make something with three columns named x for example, then there are multiple ways to create observations from columns like, gather().